# How do I create a questions and answers razor pages in ASP .NET Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

I've added two model classes `Question` and `Answer`, where one `Question` has many `Answers`.

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public long IdQuestion { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public List<Answer>? Answers { get; set; } = new List<Answer>();
}

public class Answer
{
    public Answer() { }
    [Key]
    public long IdAnswer { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    // Foreign key
    [ForeignKey("Fk_Question")]
    public long QuestionId { get; set; }
}
```

But besides the various errors I got using foreign key, the hardest thing is being to construct the logic for the razor pages.

I've created two pages, `index.cshtml` and `answers.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="~/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 class="bg-primary text-white p-2 m-2">Perguntas</h3>
        <form method="post">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <label>nome:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" class="form-control"/><br/>
            <label>Pergunta:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Description" id="Description" class="form-control" /><br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    @foreach(Question q in Model.Questions)
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                @q.Name
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                @q.Description
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                @q.IdQuestion
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="Answers?q=@q.IdQuestion"><button  class="btn btn-link">Answer</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>

@model AnswersModel
@{
    if (Model == null)
    {
        RedirectToPage("Answers");
    }
    long x;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg-primary text-center text-white">@TempData["question"]</div>
    <form method="post">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" class="form-control" /><br/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Answer">Answer:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="type your answer here" name="Description"
                id="Description" class="form-control"/>
            @*<input type="hidden" name="x" id="x" value="@x" />*@
            @TempData["qid"] = x
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    @* here it should display only the answers for this question *@
    @*@foreach(Question q in Model.Questions)
    {*@
        @foreach (Answer a in Model.Answers)
        {
            @if (TempData["qid"] != null)
            {
                x = (long)TempData["qid"];

                @if (x == a.QuestionId)
                {
                    <p>@a.Name</p>
                    <p>@a.Description</p>
                }

            }

        }
</body>
</html>
```

With respective code-behind files:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private DataContext _dataContext;
 
    public IndexModel(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public DbSet<Question> Questions => _dataContext.Questions;
    public DbSet<Answer> Answers => _dataContext.Answers;

    public IActionResult OnPost(Question q)
    {
        if(q!= null)
        {
            Questions.Add(q);
        }

        int v = _dataContext.SaveChanges();
        
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}

public class AnswersModel : PageModel
{
    DataContext dataContext;
    static long questionid = 0;

    public AnswersModel(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        this.dataContext = dataContext;
    }
    public DbSet<Answer> Answers => dataContext.Answers;
    public DbSet<Question> Questions => dataContext.Questions;

    // answer is coming empty
    public IActionResult OnGet(long q)
    {
        TempData["qid"] = q;
        foreach(Question  question in Questions)
        {
            foreach(Answer answer in Answers)
            {
                if(answer.QuestionId == q)
                {
                    TempData["question"] = question.Description;
                }
            }
        }

        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(Answer a,long x)
    { 
        Answer answer;
        TempData["qid"] = a.QuestionId;
        bool ok = false;
            foreach (Question q in Questions)
            {
                if (q.IdQuestion == questionid)
                {
                int count = q.Answers.Count;
                q.Answers.Add(answer = new Answer
                {
                    Description = a.Description,
                    Name = a.Name,
                    QuestionId = questionid,
                });
                dataContext.Answers.Add(answer);
                ok = true;
            }

            }
            if(ok)
        await dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Page();
    }
        
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm sending the id of the question as a query param and saving it statically which is clearly wrong
Now I'm using TempData to store the current question, all works except it doubles the answers and it doesn't update when i add an answer

Comment: what's the error you met exactly?

Comment: you probably want [ForeignKey("QuestionId")] public virtual Question Question { get; set; }  Right now it expects you to have a value for "Fk_Question" that would be another class object's primary key.  You want it annotated for Question object.

Comment: @Tiny right now the answers page, when i post a new answer doesn't show the previous answers

Comment: All working now i guess. thanks